# Add new variable in where clause with cross apply

Tags: sql, mysql, cross-apply

Created a new date variable in select statement, i need to add this new variable to the where clause as below;

```
         SELECT a.bim, a.cim, b.Block,
            (datename(dw, a.start_date)+ ', ' + convert  (varchar(20),a.start_date,107) ) as mmm
          FROM CK.SCHEDULE a
         LEFT JOIN ck.Lookup b on b.date1=mmm
                WHERE bim='2024'
```

This 'mmm' variable need to be equal 'date1' Tried cross apply but didnt work in this one.

```
date1 looks: Monday, July 03, 2023

  start_Date looks: 2018-07-02 00:00:00.0000000
```

Comment: where does date1 come from?

Comment: Plus is an arithmetic operator on mysql - is this question tagged correctly?

Comment: hey, i Corrected

Comment: no we need to understand the structure of the tables, so we can help you

Comment: Your SQL is not MySql and you have used a t-sql specific tag, you have not tagged your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

`mmm` is out of the scope of the `WHERE` clause. However, if you define it in a subquery then it would be in scope of the `WHERE` clause.

For example:

```
create table t (a int, b int);

insert into t (a, b) values (1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)

select *
from (
  select t.*, a + b as c from t
) x
where c > 5 -- c is in scope in the external WHERE clause
```

See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HhCSt2IH).

Comment: Is there anyway to make them equal in where clause without creating all these. The rest is huge complicated code, so it will mess up. maybe in where clause make those 2 date values equal?

Comment: Another option is to define a view on the table that computes that extra value. Then the query could use the view instead.